# Magic Particles

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, opengl-es

I really like this Particle Emitter software here:
http://www.astralax.com/projects/particles

They have an API and even an OpenGL Wrapper for IOS but I cannot figure out how to integrate these particle emitters in to my standard UIKit Xcode project.

They have a sample for Cocos2dX (not interested in that) and they have a sample using OpenGL (which is pretty advanced) but no easy sample of how I can integrate to my existing standard Xcode projects referencing from my standard .h and .m files.

Has anyone figured out how to use this program with basic Xcode?

EDIT: I guess it says I am "Off Topic"...never seen that here before. Curious, I didn't even know there was a specific topic going on. I'm confused (sort of why I made the post in the first place).

Comment: Check the link in the *off-topic* message bellow. You'd benefit from reading it. But basically what "on-topic" means is: there are some rules to post a Question, they're not difficult, but necessary to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CAEmitterLayer` extented from CALayer. See Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAEmitterLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: I can use that (especially with the new SpriteKit and few sample particle emitters) OR I can use Cocos2d with the 71squared product as well as many others...BUT I want to specifically use the Magic Particles program which means using the proprietary "PTC" files it generates which have info AND the Texture combined in 1 file. CAEmitterLayer is clueless when it comes to "PTC" files so how are you suggesting I am able to use that??